# The proof of ONE$\uparrow G_{po}^s(X) \Rightarrow$ ONE$\uparrow G_{po}(X) $.

Tags: general-topology, combinatorial-game-theory

> Let $X$ be a topological space. The **point-open game** $G_{po}(X)$ is defined as folows. It is played by two players ONE and TWO. In the n'th step $(n \in \omega)$, ONE choose a finite subset $F$ of $X$, and TWO selects an open $G_n$ in $X$, $F_n \subset G_n$. ONE wins if $\bigcup \{ G_n : n \in \omega \} = X$, otherwise TWO wins.

Also:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. The **strict point-open game** $G_{po}^s(X)$ is defined as folows. It is played by two players ONE and TWO. In the n'th step $(n \in \omega)$, ONE choose a finite subset $F$ of $X$, and TWO selects an open $G_n$ in $X$, $F_n \subset G_n$. ONE wins if $\underline {Lim} G_n  = X$, otherwise TWO wins.

Theorem 1 [here (page 154)](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0166864182900657/1-s2.0-0166864182900657-main.pdf?_tid=8bcb53ca-d11a-11e3-80b0-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1398939949_569a59d59ec63e2a5268ce0f875df400) states that ONE$\uparrow G_{po}^s(X)$ iff ONE$\uparrow G_{po}(X)$.

There is a notation in the proof which I am not familiar with and is not clear to me.
In order to prove the non-trivial direction, the autors assume that S is a winning strategy for ONE in ONE$\uparrow G_{po}(X)$. They state then, that "a sequence 
$\langle \langle F_i,G_i \rangle : i < \omega \rangle$ is compatible with S, if $F_i$ is finite, $G_i$ is open, $F_i \subset G_i$ for $i < \omega$, and, for any $k < \omega$, $S(\langle G_i : i<k \rangle) \subset F_k$".

I don't understand the meaning of the notation $S(\langle G_i : i<k \rangle)$. It is, also, not explained previously in the article. Any help?

Thank you!

p.s. ONE$\uparrow G_{po}(X)$ means: ONE has a winning strategy in $G_{po}(X)$

Comment: It looks like $S(\langle G_i:i<k\rangle)$ is the finite set that ONE chooses in his winning strategy. By this I mean that $\langle\langle S(\langle G_i:i<k\rangle),G_k\rangle:\ k<\omega\rangle$ is a win for ONE.

Comment: So, $S(\langle G_i:i<k\rangle)$ is $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} F_k$?

Comment: I meant $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} F_i$..

Comment: Not necessarily, I'd say. If ONE has a winning strategy this means that he has a first play $S(\emptyset)$ which will eventually lead to a win, whatever TWO plays. Then TWO plays $G_1$ and ONE responds with $S(G_1)$ according to his winning strategy, which will lead him to victory whatever TWO does in the following play. Then TWO plays $G_2$ and ONE answers with $S(G_1,G_2)$ and so and so forth.

Comment: @A.Bellmunt I think your comment answer the question, so perhaps you could post it as answer. (If you feel that my answer is exactly the same as what you are saying, I can remove it, so that we do not have two redundant answers.)

Comment: @ShirSivroni I think it is better to give links to papers using DOI - in this case: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(82)90065-7 In this way the link might be more stable. (DOI will be the same even if Elsevier changes the structure of their website.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: your answer is exactly what I meant in my comment. There's no need to remove it though, since it is very clear and well explained. Removing your answer so that I end up writing something very similar doesn't make sense to me. I would leave it as it is.

Comment: @A.Bellmunt Understood. The reason I wrote the suggestion that I am willing to remove the answer was only because you might feel like I have stolen the reputation which you have deserved. (Since you have said basically the same thing in a comment before I have posted that answer.) There are some people who care a lot about the reputation, so I decided that it is better to ask you explicitly.

Comment: @MartinSelziak ok I will use this kind of link. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start with two disclaimers. This is more or less what is written in [A. Bellmunt's comments above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776875/the-proof-of-one-uparrow-g-posx-rightarrow-one-uparrow-g-pox#comment1612211_776875). And I did not look at the rest of the proof, I only have tried to answer the meaning of the specific part the OP is asking about.

---

To understand the meaning of $S(\langle G_i; i<k \rangle)$ we only need to understand what is a strategy.

A strategy for the player I is a function $S$ which, depending on the moves players made so far, tells I what to play next.

So, in the first move, nothing was played so far and a strategy tells me what is $A_1$, the first set ONE should play.
I.e. $S(\langle\rangle)=A_1$. (The $\langle\rangle$ there represents the list of all moves made so far.)

Now TWO makes some move $G_1$. The strategy tells ONE what to play next. I.e. it should be $S(\langle A_1,G_1\rangle)=A_2$. But since $A_1$ is uniquely determined by the chosen strategy, the authors simply omitted it and use $S(\langle G_1\rangle)=A_2$. (I am more used to the first notation, where strategy is something which assigns the next move based on the sequence of moves of *both* players. Clearly, some people use different convention.)

In the next step, if players so far played their moves $\langle A_1,G_1,A_2,G_2\rangle$, the next move of ONE is $S(\langle G_1,G_2\rangle)=A_3$. (Or, in the notation I am used to, $S(\langle A_1,G_1,A_2,G_2\rangle)=A_3$.) And so on.

---

Let us notice one more thing. If the winning strategy tells ONE to play a set $A_n$ in the $n$-th step, if he chooses to play some finite set $F_n\supseteq A_n$, this strategy works for him, too. (Since his goal is to make the set $\liminf G_n$ as big as possible.)

---

So now the sentence you have copied from the article simply says this: We will call a sequence $\langle F_i,G_i; i<\omega\rangle$ compatible with the strategy $S$, if this sequence represents a possible run of the game, where player ONE plays exactly according to the strategy $S$. (With the minor difference, he is also allowed to choose bigger finite sets. This is why they write $S(\langle G_i; i<k\rangle)\subset F_k$ and not $S(\langle G_i; i<k\rangle)=F_k$.)

Comment: I see now. fully understood. Thank you for your detailed answer!!